# How to get the base url from a JS file?

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, base-url

I want to retrieve a base URL and append it with my module controller link from a JS file, so it's impossible to use a block to get the base URL. So far I've done this:

```
define([
   'jquery',
   'mage/url'
], function ($,url) { 

  var linkUrl = url.build('namespace_module/regions/index');
  console.log(linkUrl);
});
```

But I only got this result:

> namespace_module/regions/index

Comment: We can also use `BASE_URL` to get the base URL in js. Check the below answer to check how it works: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/336194/35758

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
define([
   'jquery',
   'mage/url'
], function ($,url) { 

  var linkUrl = url.build('frontname/regions/index');
  console.log(linkUrl);
});
```

> Where frontname is your routes.xml file frontname.

**You have to pass your frontname from routes.xml file instead of module name(namespace_module)**

You can lookup your routes.xml file from `app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

Comment: It does not work for me, it returns 'routename/controller/action' in admin js file.

Comment: Hi Rakesh,
It's working fine in frontend but what about backend.
Didn't get base url in backend using this.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/base-url-in-js-file-backend-area-magento-2/ check backend area.

Answer (score 14):

You can retrieve the `baseUrl` from the global JS variable `BASE_URL`, and use it by setting the baseUrl from the `mage/url` module.

```
define([
   'jquery',
   'mage/url'
], function ($, url) { 
  url.setBaseUrl(BASE_URL);
  var link = url.build('foo/bar');

  console.log(link); // https://magento.com/foo/bar
});
```

This will return the absolute URL.

Comment: This was actually pretty helpful addition to the accepted answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'am not sure what you are doing but i think you should pass url to js(widget). 
Url is parameter of js widget

Put script below to your template where you want

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "yourWidget": {
                    "dataUrl": "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl(); ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In javascript widget you can access to dataUrl

```
define(['uiComponent'], function(Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            console.log(this.dataUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

Another approach

```
<script>
window.testUrl = <?php echo json_encode($block->getBaseUrl()); ?>
</script>
```

In your custom js you can easy access to window.testUrl global variable

Comment: this is better because sometime the JS version bugs

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in phtml file :

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>" id="baseUrl"/>
```

Now you can use this base url in js file by id :

```
$("#baseUrl").val();
```

This may be useful. I also check it and it is working.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use **`BASE_URL`** to get base URL in js.

**How it's working**

You can see `BASE_URL` at head on every page

[image]

This is defined in require `require_js.phtml`

> vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml

Answer (score 0):

May be you can get base url from `window.checkout.baseUrl`