# How to define the url in js and how to load ajax in magento 2

Tags: url, magento2.2, jquery

**I have get all the form data after the form submit, I have submitted the form data, but it is failed to load as ajax, after submitted it reloads the page. Ajax is not working, How to overcome this issue**

```
  return function (config) {
                $('#review-form').on("click", "#review-submit", function () {

                    var form_data = $("#review-form").serialize();
                    var reviewurl = config.url;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: reviewurl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        // Pass the submitted form data to Controller
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(form_data);
                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            if (returnedData.status == 'success')
                                $("#success").html(returnedData.messages);
                            else
                                $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert("failed");
                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
```

**Contoller**

```
public function execute()
    {

        $message = null;
        $status = null;
        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $message = "Invalid form key";
            $status = 'failed';
        } else {
            //get the form data
            $data = $this->reviewSession->getFormData(true);
            if ($data) {
                $rating = [];
                if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
                    $rating = $data['ratings'];
                }
            } else {
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
                $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', []);
            }
            if (($product = $this->initProduct()) && !empty($data)) {
                /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review */
                $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->setData($data);

                $review->unsetData('review_id');

                $validate = $review->validate();
                if ($validate === true) {
                    try {
                        $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                                ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                                ->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
                                ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                                ->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                                ->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                                ->save();
                        foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
                            $this->ratingFactory->create()
                                    ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                                    ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                                    ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                                    ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
                        }
                        $review->aggregate();
                        $message = __('You submitted your review for moderation.');
                        $status = 'success';
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                        $message = __('We can\'t post your review right now.');
                        $status = 'failed';
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                    if (is_array($validate)) {
                        foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
                            $message = $errorMessage;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $message = __('We can\'t post your review right now.');
                    }
                    $status = 'failed';
                }
            }
        }
        $result['messages'] = $message;
        $result['status'] = $status;
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

Comment: which url want to declare?

Comment: Do you want to do this by ajax?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have get the url using config

Comment: Please see the updated post

Comment: @Sri don't change the questions completely after someone has added the answer. You can add a new question instead of changing the whole question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be because you forgot to `return false` which is equivalent to `e.preventDefault`. Try this code.

```
  return function (config) {
                $('#review-form').on("click", "#review-submit", function () {

                    var form_data = $("#review-form").serialize();
                    var reviewurl = config.url;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: reviewurl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        // Pass the submitted form data to Controller
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(form_data);
                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            if (returnedData.status == 'success')
                                $("#success").html(returnedData.messages);
                            else
                                $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert("failed");
                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            };
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Thank you it works, but it is popup form after submitted form it is not reloading,, but failed to show response message inside popup

Comment: And after the ajax function i need to close popup modal

Comment: Okay, dont you see the alert(form_data)? Try to use network debugger to see the ajax requests and response. Make sure correct controller is being hit. Before you try to alert the response just simply alert some random string.

Comment: Hi Anime, Thank you, after showing the response mesg I need to close the popup modal

Comment: But How do i close the popup after form submitted

Comment: You can write $('your_jquery-selector-for-modal').hide() at last in your success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70802/discussion-between-sri-and-anime).

Answer (score 6):

You can use php in javascript variable.

```
<script>
var url = "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'frontname/controller/action' ?>"; // use php in js variable.
</script>
```

OR you can add '**mage/url**' in your script as given below

```
define([
   'jquery',
   'mage/url'
], function ($,url) { 

  var linkUrl = url.build('frontname/controller/action');
  console.log(linkUrl);
});
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188492/48571)

Comment: Hello @Dinesh, for me second solution logged frontname/controller/action. I have seen this solution many times but never worked for me. I thought that it would prepend the baseurl with above string.

Comment: you have to change these names as per your module.  frontname=> your frontname defined in etc/frontend/routes.xml file. controller=> your controller name. action=> your controller's action name.

Comment: I know that, but I'm confused by the output linkUrl is it not supposed to be baseurl/frontname/controller/action??

Comment: @Sri don't change the questions completely after someone has added the answer. You can add a new question instead of changing the whole question.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
define([
   'jquery',
   'mage/url'
], function ($,url) { 
  var moduleURL = url.build('ar/controller-name/action-name');
  console.log(moduleURL);
});
```

**OR**

Use direct in phtml file

```
<script>
    var url = "<?php echo $block->getUrl('frontname/controller/action')?>";
</script>
```