# How to get Base URL in magento 2 admin script?

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, base-url

I Have added a script ( JS File ) in Magento 2 admin side in my custom module.
It added successfully but how to get Base URL in admin side js file.

I have tried this

Js file path ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/view/adminhtml/web/js/adminscript.js )

```
require([
 'mage/url'
], function (urlBuilder) {
 var customLink = urlBuilder.build('customer/account/login');
console.log(customLink);
});
```

But it gives me the current page full URL.

My layout file path ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/view/adminhtml/layout/adminsample_sampletwo_index.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link src="Tym17_AdminSample::js/adminscript.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Tym17\AdminSample\Block\Adminhtml\Order" name="Overview" template="Tym17_AdminSample::sample/two.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**How to get only base url like this http://127.0.0.1/magento/**

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188484/get-base-url-from-js-file

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    require([
     "prototype"
    ], function () {
        window.customUrl = '<?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getUrl('sales/order/index')?>';
    });
</script>
```

Now you can use Global variable inside your custom js file,

var customUrl = window.customUrl;
You can get the backend URL using the above variable in the js file.

Comment: Mark answer as right, it its helpful to you

Comment: Thanks for your response but When i added this script part in my phtml file and used  this customUrl = window.customUrl; in my js file but it gives me undefined @Hamendra

Comment: you need to add like var url = <?php echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>

Comment: Where in my phtml file i have to add var url = <?php echo $block->getUrl(''); ?> and then try to get url in js file.
Am i correct please help ? @Hamendra

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
require([
   'mage/url'
], function (urlBuilder) {
  var customLink = urlBuilder.build('customer/account/login');
  console.log(customLink);
});
```

And check more information this link :-

**https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-custom-url-in-js-file-magento-2/**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Thanks for your response but it gives me an error :
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (urlBuilder) {
  var customLink = urlBuilder.build('customer/account/login');
  console.log(customLink);
} will you please help @Mohit

Comment: please share your full code ...

Comment: Hello @Prits i have update my answer.And i have change `defined` Instead `require`

Comment: It gives me customer/account/login in console.
I have updated my adminsample_sampletwo_index.xml and js file. Please check @Mohit

Comment: Please clear your new actually problem ...

Comment: Actually i just want Base Url ex: http://127.0.0.1/magento/ in my admin js file and i have added code for xml file how i add my js file and my js file code Hope you got it please help @Mohit

Answer (score 0):

If you want baseurl in js then can we achieve using this "BASE_URL"

For more please inspect element and find for "BASE_URL"

Thanks